# What Off-Topic Close Reasons do we need?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Right now, we can use three custom off-topic reasons. This is what we have:

- Theme or plugin recommendation requests are off-topic as they're rarely helpful to others. For more information, visit meta.
- Programming questions not specific to WordPress are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.
- Questions on problems with a specific host or provider are off-topic here. Please contact the appropriate support department instead.

We have to catch the old *too localized* here, so we need to change those pre-made reasons.

The last one is not common enough, or it can be grouped with other problems, for example.

Your suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New close reason are live. [Discussed suggestions in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/conversation/creating-the-new-off-topic-messages) and had to do some shuffling to fit under character limits and pack everything needed into three slots.

Answer (score 9):

The close reason about *programming questions* is too narrow. How about this?

> Questions about programming, HTML, CSS or JavaScript and *not* specific to WordPress are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: We also have unspecific blogging/management and generic server config as not in scope. Maybe make close reason more generic and link to that for full details? ~ "Questions about generic concepts and technologies which are not specific to WordPress (even if they happen in its context), see [link]...".

Comment: @Rarst Please add your own suggestions as separate answers.

Answer (score 4):

Our most common *too localized* questions were about syntax errors or themes and plugins with closed source. So I suggest a close reason for that:

> Questions about syntax errors, hacked sites, or plugins and themes whose code is not accessible are off-topic because they will not help any future visitors. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not sure if this isn't too narrow. On the other hand we could extend to "(...) and impossible to answer without public code/source".

Comment: This sounds to me as "off-topic because without code". I think the more accurate way to formulate is "impossible to answer without code". Even question about no-source product can be useful and net good answers, if specific of code itself aren't involved.

Comment: @Rarst & toscho: [Live example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/104914/12615). I'm not sure how to word a custom *vote to close* message. Would this proposal be `"Questions about syntax errors or plugins and themes whose code is not accessible are off-topic because it's impossible to answer without code.`? Maybe: *"without the relevant portions of the code"*?

Answer (score 4):

> Questions with extremely narrow requirements, requiring hands-on involvement (hacks recovery) or access (code behind paywalls) are not a good fit for QA format and [scope of the site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

This picks up "too localized" and bolts free-work/need-access to it to fit more stuff in 3 reason slots.

Answer (score 4):

> Recommendations for products (plugins, themes, books, hosting providers and other) were made [out of scope of the site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in line with [community decision on meta](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations).

Expands on recommendations, both more generic and mentions more specific things (so we don't get "but I asked for a book/hosting/puppy, not a plugin!" confusion).

Comment: Not so sure about the _other_. Every answer recommends something: a solution.

Comment: @toscho as in "other _products_", not "other _anything_".

Comment: Ah, missed that somehow. What about _Give me all the links about X?_

Comment: @toscho I think depending on context "too broad" or "primarily opinion based" likely to cover that one.

Answer (score 2):

> Questions should be **specific to WordPress** within [defined scope](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (merely happening in its context is insufficient). Might be better asked at [other site of SE network](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic).

Emphasis on "specific" (better than "not not specific" since mind tends to jumps over "not"s when reading). Not much space for multiple stacks recommendations so just link to list of stacks, filtered to technology.

Answer (score 2):

This one is similar to @Rarst's [proposal](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2518), but mixed with Stack Overflow text. Instead of explicitly declaring our discussion to make plugin/theme recommendations off-topic, simply link it inside "product".

> Questions asking us to recommend a product ([plugins, themes, books, hosting providers](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217)), tool, library or favorite off-site resource are [out of scope of the site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.