# Can I ask wordpress plugin recommend question on this site?

Tags: support

Can I ask wordpress plugin recommend question on this site?

I want to let my site provide the database's data to REST APIs for my mobile development, but I am not sure whether there have those type plugins. I want to ask for recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but no, asking for a plugin or theme recommendation is off-topic here.

See [Update our FAQ and abandon theme/plugin recommendations](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations)

You might have some luck on the wordpress.org support forum.