# end "shopp"ing: eliminate the tag "plugin-shopp'

Tags: discussion, tags

I propose the tag "plugin-shopp" to be eliminated (I don't know if you can use here on this Meta the term "burninate" like on Stackoverflow).

The tag's [wiki](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/plugin-shopp/info) says it is off-topic. It has currently 1 watcher and 10 questions, the newest from 2014

Their own [plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shopp/) says it hasn’t been tested with the latest 3 major releases of WordPress (that was 8 month ago)

I don't think it makes sense to keep this tag.

**edit:**
as suggested by @rene here are the missing insights why I think we should eliminate this tag: see [When to Burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/251777)

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Yes.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Yes.

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Yes.

Anyway, the "burnination" criteria seems to not to be applicable here, as there is no such process. Therefore I plea of removal of this tag.

**all plugin-shopp** [questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-shopp)

Comment: You could maybe apply the criteria mentioned in the [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/158100) answer over on MSE. Without being a subject matter expert or regular on Wordpress.se I don't think the arguments you currently use to burn the tag are reason enough to warrant removal. But that is just my opinion, the community here needs to chime in on this.

Comment: @rene I've just updated the OP reflecting on your comment

Comment: The tag does describe the contents of the question. All questions I checked were about that Shopp plugin. The tag adds meaningful info as it enable users that are capable of answering such question to find them. There is no doubt that this tag means the same thing wherever it is used. So instead of four *No*'s there should be at least three **Yes**'s. I really doubt this burninate request has merit to be taken on. Coming up with a solid Burnination Request is hard. If I had the reputation to down vote this request I would have done so by now.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

You're right. This tag should be deleted. Because it's off-topic now.
See below a detailed explanation why.

### It's all about asking *how*, not *what* to use or to install

You want to use a *specific plugin* so that you could *add some functionality* to your WordPress website, *you know what you want to accomplish*, you only need to formulate your question to how to develop this yourself (in your own WP theme or plugin).

So just [ask *how* you should do what you want to do](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and leave the plugin recommendations - if any - to the answerers.

- Maybe someone recommends a great *plugin*, *library* or *framework* and includes an
  example of how to use it.
- Maybe someone points out that there's a standard library routine to do what you want.
- Maybe someone writes a short bit of code that does it from scratch.
- Maybe it's impossible or unfeasible and someone tells you that.

By asking how to do something instead of what to use or to install you're not only learning something from it (and therefore becoming a better Web/WordPress developer) but you've also invited answers that will be more useful to you, now, and others, in the future.

### The plugin is not maintained anymore

It looks like the plugin Shopp is *outdated* and *not actively maintained anymore*, see: https://wordpress.org/plugins/shopp/

### The rules/guidelines

> Asking to recommend a product ([plugin, theme, book, hosting
>   provider](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations)), tool, library or off-site resource is [out of the scope
>   of this website](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as it attracts opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to
>   solve it.