# Update Community Specific Closure Dialogue Links from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

All currently active Community Specific closure reasons use links that are http and not https.

For example (non HTTPS links indicated with code formatting):

- Questions that are **too localized** (such as syntax errors, code with restricted access, hacked sites, hosting or support issues) are `[not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)`. See `[how do I ask a good question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)`
- Asking to recommend a product ([plugin, theme, book, hosting provider](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217)), tool, library or off-site resource is `[out of scope of the site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)`, as it attracts opinionated answers and spam. Instead, `[describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/139399/)` and what has been done so far to solve it.
- Your question should be `[specific to WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)`. Generic PHP/JS/SQL/HTML/CSS questions might be better asked at [so] or another `[appropriate Stack Exchange network site](http://s.tk/sites#technology)`. Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' support routes.

Can these be updated to https or relative links?

Comment: Note: The "MSO" link in the close reason for product (etc.) recommendations points to what is now the stub of an MSE post that has since actually been migrated to MSO: [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously, the Help Center links in all the close reasons were absolute links, with URLs starting with `http://`. I've changed them to be relative links instead (e.g. `/help/on-topic`), which should ensure that they use HTTPS (since anyone accessing the site should already be seeing an HTTPS version of the page).

I've also expanded the http://s.tk/sites link to use the full https://stackexchange.com/sites URL instead, and fixed the broken MSO link to point to (the HTTPS version of) the right Q&A (plus some other minor copyediting).

---

That said, y'all should consider updating all of your community-specific close reasons to use the 5 available fields. [See this MSO post for an example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418095/1478931) (note that "Privileged user guidance" has been changed to "Public guidance"). You can do this for all of the custom close reasons for Wordpress.SE; each one should have its own meta discussion to allow the community to come to an agreement about what the content of the fields should be.

As explained in [Catija's answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362584/335251), the fields available for each close reason are:

1. **Brief description** (100 characters) – The bolded portion visible in the list of community-specific close reasons in the close/flag dialog. This should be very succinct, only spanning a couple of words (e.g. "Too localized" or "Not specific to WordPress").
2. **Usage guidance** (500 characters) – The text that appears in the close/flag dialog below the brief description. This should tell close voters when to use the close reason (and when not to use it). Ideally, this is descriptive enough to cover edge cases, and that detail should inspire confidence in close voters that this reason is the right choice under specified circumstances.
3. **Post notice close description** (500 characters) – The text (visible to all users) that appears at the top of the post notice on a question closed with this reason. This should follow the format "*This question was **closed** because it is ... It is not currently accepting answers.*"
4. **Post owner guidance** (500 characters) – This text is shown only to the post author, appearing below the close description in the post notice on a question closed with this reason. This should explain to the author why their question was closed, and provide guidance on how to improve their post to get it reopened (if possible). Helpful links to the help center or a relevant meta post are also good to include here.
5. **Public guidance** (500 characters) - This text is shown to all other users, appearing below the close description in the post notice (where the post owner guidance appears to the author). This should inform other users how best to guide the asker in improving their question (if possible).

(Site moderators can also see the Stack Moderators Team for more detailed guidance on how to craft community-specific close reasons using the new format.)

Once you've discussed what these fields should be changed to for a close reason, and the community has come to a consensus, a site moderator can add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to escalate it for CM attention. Then we will review the discussion, and make the requested changes (if appropriate).

Comment: Taking care of all my close reason related posts today =)

Answer (score 2):

I've changed the `http` to `https` in the [on-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Help Center article ("What topics can I ask about here?"), amongst other changes to clarify another question that was asked.