# Are Questions on Settings Adjustments in WordPress Core or Third Party Themes and Plugins Allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, off-topic

I'm trying to find out how to display a line number next to my hundreds of posts in the back end so I can clearly see where I left off. Not sure if there is a plugin or if this would require coding.

From these two posts I learned that "shopping" questions are not allowed here:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
- [Update our FAQ and abandon theme/plugin recommendations](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations)

So, my question is where do questions about WordPress core settings and configuration belong? Settings aren't exactly coding, but if they are WordPress core and the answers can't be found in the WordPress.org forums, where should they be directed?

Comment: Core here, third-party in their issue queues or maybe https://wordpress.slack.com.

Comment: note that you aren't very clear on what you mean by settings and configuration, and your initial example doesn't appear related to settings and configuration

Answer (score 5):

Note that since settings/configuration was never defined by the asker and no examples were given, I've written by answer using these definitions:

- **settings**, options available via the user interface, e.g the customizer, site editor, or settings pages.
- **configuration**, a larger scope that could include the above, but could also include `wp-config.php` constants, PHP environment variables, nginx configs, and other PHP code or server/dev ops.

It is noted that the one example shared appears to be unrelated to both of them. It's also noted that these are not comprehensive dictionary definitions, it isn't my intention to provide a cast iron definition of the two.

### Are Questions on Settings Adjustments in WordPress Core Allowed?

As long as they are programming/developer questions, as this is a stack for developers, not end users.

For example, what a constant defined in `wp-config.php` does, or how to set the default value of a setting are ok. Those are programming questions.

Changing values in the browser in the default settings however is end user support which isn't appropriate for this stack. If it's something that can be answered by telling you to click buttons or fill in text boxes in the browser then that's in the realm of end user support and outside the stacks scope. E.g. changing the size of thumbnails in the media settings page, or the number of posts shown on archives on general settings.

### Are Questions on Settings Adjustments in Third Party Themes and Plugins Allowed?

No. 3rd party plugin and theme dev support questions are offtopic and not in the scope of this stack. Contact their respected vendors support routes or ask in their associated communities.

### Follow Up Notes

The presence of a plugin that answers does what you're asking in your question is irrelevant. You can ask how to do something, but you can't ask for a recommendation for a plugin that does it for you.

Take the opening of your question:

> I'm trying to find out how to display a line number next to my hundreds of posts in the back end so I can clearly see where I left off.

This would be on topic and in scope, you're asking how to do it, someone could write an answer with some code and walk you through the steps.

> Not sure if there is a plugin or if this would require coding.

This however, is off-topic. There's a difference between these:

- How do I implement ABC?
- Is there an ABC plugin?

Comment: -1 to "As long as they're programming questions". server admin and therefor admin in general should be part of the site. It is just that asking about how to increase the number of comments shows no effort, not that it is invalid question. (this is a very low example, but there are many other settings that are not that obvious)

Comment: the distinction was between developers and users, your definition of a programming question is not a shared iron-cast universal absolute, I'd also add that you too haven't defined what you mean by a setting

Comment: everything about core settings should be legitimate question. A better example for such is "what is the difference between home url and site url". You can find the answer on duckduckgo but you can also find there answers about code as well. As for users vs developers, as long as admins can edit plugins and themes from the core UI, they are potentially developers

Comment: Editing plugins and themes is still coding wether you do it via the admin UI or via a code editor, it's comparing apples and pears. home url vs site url is also a bad example because you're conflating 2 independent questions, one is an end user asking why there are 2 separate input boxes, whereas a coder may ask the same question with a very different meaning and answer.

Comment: in the end of the day, admins are not end users, no more than wordpress implementors at least. Not sure why you think that a question on the level of $i++ is more legitimate than how to setup comment feed. both are part of making a site work the way the owner want. Don't think that differenciating between questions if they can be answered  by code or by setting is very useful.